# @Transactional Error after upgrade Spring

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have class in my project like this:

```
@Transactional (value = EBTransactionConfig.NAME, readOnly = true)
public class Main {
       public void update(CreateUpdateSomethingInDto inDto) {
          (...)
          updateSomething(inDto);
       }

        @Transactional (value = EBTransactionConfig.NAME)
        public void updateSomething((CreateUpdateSomethingInDto inDto) {
           (...)
           repository.saveAndFlush(inDto);
       }
}
```

Why acutally I have error but before upgrade spring I didn't have??

Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback:null, nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback:null, validationErrors=[]} created for exception: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to perform  beforeTransactionCompletion callback:null at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:353)

Comment: Could you post the error too?

Comment: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback:null, nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to perform  beforeTransactionCompletion  callback:null, validationErrors=[]} created for exception: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: (..)

Comment: Try to edit the original post and put the full stackTrace into it. This helps all the readers. org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException is a Spring wrapper exceptions for JPA errors which don't match Spring JPA ones.